# Weird Error on Visual Studio - "you could use the navigation bar to switch context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have been trying to link a a web form to be a able to access a variable in the master page. I did this before it worked. But now when I do it I get an error.

The code in Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>
```

The code in Site.Master.cs

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string hi = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The code in WebForm1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
```

The Code in WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Master.hi="new"
     }
}
```

When I hover over the hi, I get this message

[Error in Visual Studio - "You can use navigation bar to switch contexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rLlw.png)

Here is another image 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmpZ6.png)

If you guys could help me it will really be great

Comment: @Sachu, I just added the image.

Comment: u r missing the semicolon `Master.hi="new";`

Comment: @Sachu I get the error when I hover over the "hi" If I add the semicolon I get this error when I run
________
'Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'hi' and no extension method 'hi' accepting a first argument of type 'MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Devry - Advanced Web Dev Project Z:\Developer\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Devry - Advanced Web Dev Project\Devry - Advanced Web Dev Project\WebForm1.aspx.cs 12'

Comment: hope this link will help u [link]http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1507/how-to-access-master-page-variableproperty-from-the-content-page

Comment: Hi @MosesAronov, Did you find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same issue now, in an asp.net MVC project.

Comment: Did you find what the hell that stupid error means!??

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem in an MVC application so the WebForm-CodeFile-CodeBehind suggestion didn't really apply.

However, I realized the new classes that I created had their "Build Action" set to "Content". Once I changed this to "Compile", everything started working again.

Answer (score 7):

In your WebForm1.aspx, try changing CodeFile to CodeBehind. That's what worked for me.

Comment: it's the correct answer... thank you for saving my day and arse! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding manual the ID of the form into the designer "yourname".aspx.designer.cs, in your case I guess it should be WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs.

You'll see a reference line for every id you have. You need to add a line like this -> "protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm hi" if you added the form like normal html 
or -> "protected global::System.Web.UI.FormView hi" if you added as an aspx element